# Check two id's on button press

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my current code:

```
<script>
$('#register').click(function (e) {
    if ($('#company_f').val().length == 0) {
        $('#company_f').css("border", "solid 1px red");
        return false; // or e.preventdefault();
    }
});
</script>
```

How can i changed this code to check for id company_f and telephone_f? This is what i've tried:

```
if ($('#company_f').val().length == 0 OR ($('#telephone_f').val().length == 0 ) {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OR` operator in JavaScript is two pipes: `||`. Either way, if you want to check both conditions you need an AND operator: `&&`

```
if ($('#company_f').val().length == 0 && $('#telephone_f').val().length == 0) {
```